# How to convert char[] to UTF-8 byte[] in C#?

Tags: c#, java, .net

I'm porting a Java function as below codes to C#, it converts a char array to UTF-8 format, and then convert to byte array, how can do this in .Net platform via C#?

Java code:

```
public static byte[] GetBytes(char[] chars) 
{
    Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.allocate(chars.length);
    cb.put(chars);
    cb.flip();
    ByteBuffer bb = cs.encode(cb);
    byte[] array = bb.array();

    return array
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte[] array = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(new string(chars));
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, have a look at class [System.Text.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx). It has plenty of methods and static members to work with encoding.

`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Some string");`
`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(charArray);`